# Voice alteration/modification software (other than Audacity)

Tags: windows, audio, audio-editing

I'm looking for voice alteration/modification software for Windows. I need it for work with audio files.

It could be that there is only so much which can be done with a voice, but the SW options that I'm familiar with seem to be very poor in the sense that for the most part they don't do much.

The best piece I came across so far seems to be Audacity which changes your voice via pitch change and a few other characteristics of your voice, but you're left with a comical version of your voice and the altering is in the best case scenario extremely obvious.

Do you know of any piece - either free and simple or expensive and complex - which does a better job?

Comment: What's the goal? Your objection to Aduacity is that the result is "comical" and "the altering is… obvious", which suggests you don't want to use this for a joke and you don't want to be recognized. But then, what do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well, it is not at all that I don't want to be recognized. My voice sounds like that of a delinquent with a lisp I would like that the modification isn't recognized... I would like to do YouTube content and not need to outsource to voice actors...