# Good application for changing voice?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, voice-recording

I need to make voice nicer. I need free or at least cheap application. Android and Windows are acceptable, but better for Ubuntu if possible. I tried Audacity - but couldn't change it enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47539

Answer (score 1):

I use Cubase which is good but not cheap. There are GNU projects trying the FOSS equivalent of Cubase that you can look at. Then you can get a plugin and many effects. I think that your question might be better suited for https://sound.stackexchange.com/